# Key Manager Database Design

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-design

My task is to add some functionality to an existing web application using SQL Server.

My client's business provides a service where keys are issued to employees who then go to the various locations to perform the requested work.  She wants to keep track of who has what keys for their clients.  They have about 100-125 clients and 6 employees.  She will be the only person using the web gui for the issuance and returning of keys.

For inspiration, I went to Google and found a demo program called KEY ORGANIZER which runs on the desktop.  It does exactly what my client is looking for but is a desktop app, not a web app.  So, I figured I’d just reverse engineer it and tailor it for my client’s needs.  The desktop application does way more than my client needs.  Here is a high level overview of what she is looking for:

**Issuing of Keys:**

1. She clicks on the key image next her customer’s name. Let’s say she has 3 keys for the customer but all 3 are already checked out to employees. She would receive an alert of some kind stating there are no keys available to issue but would still allow her to issue a key in situations were inventory is off (so the database needs to be able to handle negative values).  If there is a key available, then proceed to the next bullet.
2. In the next window, she is presented with a form.  (list of employees name to choose from and today's date).
3. She selects the employee from the drop down list and clicks the OK button and the modal window closes.
4. A log entry is entered for every check-out/check-in and an email will be sent to the employee upon each check-in and check-out.

**Returning of Keys:**

1. She would also like to be able to select a button next to an client’s name to see which employees currently has a key and be able to select an employee’s name to return a key.
2. Similarly, my client would like to click on the employee’s name to see if a list of keys in their possession and be able to return a key from the list, too.
3. A log entry is entered for every check-out/check-in and an email will be sent to the employee upon each check-in and check-out.

I do not need help with the coding of the web page. I just need some guidance on how to properly setup the database tables (e.g. should the key inventory field be a part of an existing table or a different table for example) to best handle the revolving key inventory scenario.

Here are the tables I’ve come up with:

**Customer_tbl** (existing table)
    • CustomerID
    • KeyQTY (new field?)
    • KeyLabel (new field?)

**Employee_tbl** (existing table)
    • EmployeeID
    • Fn
    • Ln

**KeyJournal_tbl** (new table)
    • JournalID
    • ActionDate
    • ActionPerformedID (key issue, key returned, key lost, etc)
    • CustomerID
    • EmployeeID
    • Inventory (the total number of keys received from the customer – or should this be under Customer_tbl?)
    • IssueReturnDate

**KeyInventory_tbl** (new table)
    • KeyID
    • CustomerID
    • KeyTotal

**NOTE**:  I added the SQL Server 2005 tag only for reference.  I don't need help with the SQL statements in case that tag is misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My inclination would be something pretty close to yours. Here:

```
Customer
  customer_id
  name, address, etc, whatever reference info you need

Employee
  employee_id
  name, etc

KeyInventory
  key_id
  description
  customer_id
  qty

KeyCheckout
  employee_id
  key_id
  checkout_date
  return_date
```

Notes:

I put a description on KeyInventory because I'm assuming you could have more than one key for a customer and you need to distinguish them, like "Apt 1" and "Apt 2", or "Warehouse" and "Office".

When an employee is given a key, create a KeyCheckout record with the date it was given. When the key is returned, fill in the return date. If the return date is null the key is still out.

To find which employees have keys for customer @cx:

select employee_id
  from KeyCheckout c
  join KeyInventory i on i.key_id = c.key_id
  where i.customer_id = @cx
    and c.return_date is null

To find how many of key @kx are still available:

select i.qty - count(c.employee_id)
  from KeyInventory i
  join KeyCheckout c on c.key_id=i.key_id and c.return_date is not null
  where i.key_id = @kx

Etc.

You'd definitely want an index on return_date, or maybe KeyCheckout(key_id,return_date) and KeyCheckout(employee_id,return_date), because this table will grow quite large and without an index queries will get unbearably slow.

I think your Journal table is a similar concept to my Checkout. I'm just putting the checkout and return fields in one record to make it easier to determine if a key is still out. With separate records for in and out, you have to match them up, which is a pain.

Don't put the qty into a journal-type record. That's not an attribute of the "transaction", it's an attribute of the key itself. It belongs in the inventory table.

Don't put the key qty in the customer record. If you need to know how many different keys a customer has, just do select count(*) from keyinventory where customer_id=@cx. Storing this count in the customer record just creates the possibility that it won't match the actual number of key records.

I'm not sure what "keylabel" is. If that's a description of the key, it belongs in the KeyInventory record, because a customer could have more than one key. I don't think it makes sense to say that a customer can have only one key. Even if that happens to be true of your customers today, it seems likely that a customer could have multiple keys in the future, might as well allow for it.

I think your inventory is non-serialized, i.e. 3 keys for the same lock are not distinguished from each other, it's just "quantity 3", right? If they have individual serial numbers on them or something, then there would be no quantity field and you'd have individual records for each key.

Comment: Your response is exactly the kind of response I was hoping for but wasn't expecting.  Your explanation makes perfect sense and your statement of `Don't put the qty into a journal-type record. That's not an attribute of the "transaction", it's an attribute of the key itself. It belongs in the inventory table.` really brought it home for me.  I was using `KeyLabel` where you used `description`  Thank you very much for writing the detailed answer and for taking the time to do so.

Comment: It was more fun than fixing the spacing on a web page, which is what I was supposed to be doing!